# Freezing during installation splashscreen

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, freeze

I have tried installing Ubuntu onto my laptop but it freezes on the purple flash screen randomly. Here's a screenshot of the console frozen [the console screen during installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Aeu.jpg)

P.S I have tried to install cloudready (Chromium OS) to my laptop but it failed, so I am trying to overwrite it with Ubuntu then install Windows 10. I am running Ubuntu 19.10.

P.P.S I have also did a drive check and it showed 1 error.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu, but did you verify the downloaded ISO as flawless, also verify the write to your install media?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any install media, be it CD/DVD/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/etc)

Comment: Latest release 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, on the installation menu, try disabling some kernel parameters (press <kbd>F6</kbd>, navigate with arrows then select with space bar). For example, disable the raid mode.

Comment: Wdym by F6? it did nothing in the grub menu.